# Display problems with (UTF-8) Data from SQL-Server in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, utf-8, sqlsrv, charset

I have a Webserver:

```
Win-Server (2008) 
Apache 2.2.25 
PHP 5.4.32 
PHPinfo says default_charset: "no value"
```

The Database Server is a MS - SQL-Server 10.50.6000.34 With Collation "Latin1_General_CI_AS"

I connect the DB with this function:

```
$connection_options = array('Database' => $this -> database, 'UID'=>$this -> user, 'PWD'=>$this -> password);   
    $this -> connection = sqlsrv_connect($this -> server, $connection_options);
    if ($this -> connection === false) {
      echo "<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
      throw new Exception("Datenbankverbindung nicht möglich.");
    }
```

When a user submits some Data through a form Letters like the German "ä,ö,ü" look like this: "Ã¼, Ãœ, ..."
When I read the data from the DB and do `mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8')` it displays ok on the website.

Our IT now copied the DB to a SQL-Server with version 14.0.2037.2 Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and I had to switch to a Linux Server:

```
RHEL8
Apache 2.4.37
PHP 7.3.20
PHP default_charset is set to UTF-8 here.
```

On the new Server the "Ã¼, Ãœ, ..." chars get displayed as is.
The Database connection is used in the same way as on the old server.

When I change the connection options to:

```
 $connection_options = array('Database' => $this -> database, 'UID'=>$this -> user, 'PWD'=>$this -> password, 'CharacterSet'=>'UTF-8');
```

It doesnt change anything.

Is there a way to convert the characters on the SQL server to they UTF-8 counterparts or can I use a differnt way to display the text from the DB on the website?
Normally I´m good with google and fiddling out whats the problem but in this case im kinda stuck. :-/

Comment: You've changed collation, so I would expect the values to change. You, however, need to show the code you are using to *`INSERT`* the data into your database. SQL Server 2017 and prior don't support UTF-8, so inserting UTF-8 values into it isn't going to work.

Comment: @Larnu the INSERT is just a simple:
`$str_SQL = "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('".$POST['val']."')";
sqlsrv_query($this -> connection, $str_SQL);`

I understood that the UTF-8 Val got split up into two chars due to the "No UTF-( problem in SQL Server". Years too late :(

Comment: That is *wide* open to injection attacks, @DerMega . That **needs** fixing. **Parametrise** your queries...

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the hint. Its a company internal website. It´s not available for the net but I understand your concern and hope it´s not too complicated to implement this sitewide.

Comment: You have *far* too much trust in your fellow co-workers then, @DerMega .

Comment: Thats perhabs right. I am too trusting of others.

@berend thanks for the link but its for mySQL not for MS-SQL.

Comment: I would, however, not be surprised if you fixing your code, and parametrising it, fixes the problem here.

Comment: @Larnu we will see. At least when I´ve understood how I can easily parametrize hindrets of queries :)
I´ll let u know.